# Load data from CSV to Database tables in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I was able to load country and state successfully, but I get error when the city is being loaded

> Something went wrong saving this city: 0000000698
>   The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.

This is my 3 models "country", "state" and "city"

```
class Country(BaseModel):
    id = models.CharField(
            primary_key=True,
            max_length=3,
            unique=True
        )

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'country'
```

```
class State(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(
            primary_key=True,
            max_length=3,
            unique=True
        )
    country = models.ForeignKey(
            Country, 
            on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
            blank=True, 
            null=True
        )
    state_code =  models.CharField(
            max_length=4,
            null=True,
            blank=True,
            unique=True
        )
    capital_city =  models.CharField(
            max_length=10,
            null=True,
            blank=True,
        )

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'state'
```

```
class City(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(
            primary_key=True,
            max_length=10,
            unique=True
        )

    country = models.ForeignKey(
            Country, 
            on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
            blank=True, 
            null=True
        )

    state = models.ForeignKey(
        State,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )


    class Meta:
        db_table = 'city'
```

This is sample CSV files I want to upload

*country.csv*

```
10,Antarctica,Antarktika
16,American Samoa,Amerikanisch-Samoa
60,Bermuda,Bermuda
74,Bouvet Island,Bouvetinsel
```

state.csv

```
1,276,BW,0000000111,Baden-Württemberg,Baden-Württemberg
2,276,BY,0000000165,Bavaria,Bayern
3,276,BE,0000000028,Berlin,Berlin
4,276,BB,0000000019,Brandenburg,Brandenburg
5,276,HB,0000000195,Bremen,Bremen
6,276,HH,0000000255,Hamburg,Hamburg
```

city.csv

```
0000000001,276,BB,Bernau bei Berlin,Bernau bei Berlin
0000000002,276,BB,Blankenfelde-Mahlow,Blankenfelde-Mahlow
0000000003,276,BB,Brandenburg an der Havel,Brandenburg an der Havel
0000000004,276,BB,Cottbus,Cottbus
0000000005,276,BB,Eberswalde,Eberswalde
0000000029,276,BW,Aalen (Württemberg),Aalen (Württemberg)
0000000030,276,BW,Achern (Baden),Achern (Baden)
0000000031,276,BW,Albstadt (Württemberg),Albstadt (Württemberg)
0000000032,276,BW,Backnang,Backnang
0000000209,276,HE,Dillenburg,Dillenburg
0000000210,276,HE,Dreieich,Dreieich
0000000211,276,HE,Eschborn (Taunus),Eschborn (Taunus)
0000000212,276,HE,Flörsheim am Main,Flörsheim am Main
```

Here is my view/logic for importing "city.csv"

```
def import_city_from_file(self):
        data_folder = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'app_name', 'resources/city_csv')
        for data_file in os.listdir(data_folder):
            with open(os.path.join(data_folder, data_file), encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
                data = csv.reader(data_file)
                for data_object in data:
                    id = data_object[0]

                    if data_object[1] != '':
                        country = models.Country.objects.get(pk=(data_object[1]),)
                    else:
                        country= models.Country.objects.get(pk = 1)

                    if data_object[2] != '':
                        state = models.State.objects.filter(pk=(data_object[2]))
                        print(state)

                    else:
                        state= models.State.objects.filter(pk = 1)

                    long_description_eng = data_object[3]
                    long_description_deu = data_object[4]


                    try:
                        city, created = models.City.objects.get_or_create(
                                id=id,
                                country_id=country,
                                state_id = state,
                                long_description_eng=long_description_eng,
                                long_description_deu=long_description_deu,

                            )
                        if created:
                            city.save()
                            display_format = "\nCity, {}, has been saved."
                            print(display_format.format(city))
                    except Exception as ex:
                        print(str(ex))
                        msg = "\n\nSomething went wrong saving this city: {}\n{}".format(id, str(ex))
                        print(msg)
```

Here is the error an getting when i attempt to import the CSV file for city
[image]

I will appreciate any help to resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

In your city `get_or_create` method you used *country* and *state* fields. In this situtation, your country and state variables must an object. But your variables are queryset (`state = models.State.objects.filter(pk=(data_object[2]))` this code returns a queryset.) If you sure that this state existed, you can use `get()` method instead of `filter()` method.) Also if you use state_id in your city `get_or_create` code params, use city.id not a city object.So, you must change two section:

```
country= models.Country.objects.filter(pk = 1).first()

state = models.State.objects.filter(pk=data_object[2]).first()
''' this code return None if you have not any state object with this pk, 
    or you can use get() method but it raise DoesNotExist error, 
    you must     implement catching it 
'''

....


City.objects.get_or_create(
                            id=id,
                            country_id=country.id if country else None,
                            state_id = state.id if state else None,
                            long_description_eng=long_description_eng,
                            long_description_deu=long_description_deu,

                        )
```

Comment: When I use the `get()`, i get error `webapp.models.DoesNotExist: RecordSet matching query does not exist.`  Can please explain to me about what you mean by this "Also if you use state_id in your city get_or_create code params, use city.id not a city object."

Comment: Normally we can use  for ForeignKeyField realated object or id of related object in queries. So if you use state_id inside your query, you must give id of state as a value.city param also like this. For the get method error, if you haven't any object suitable for parameters, get method raise DoesNotExist error, you must be careful about it.

Comment: @AzeezOluwasegunAkinsola I updated my answer, please look at again

Comment: Ok. Thank you @kamilyrb. I will check that now

Comment: Now the `querysey` of state `state = models.State.objects.filter(pk=(data_object[2]).first()` is not returning any result, is returning none. When i use like this `all()` and `values()`, It returns result. What do I need to change here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208764/discussion-between-azeez-oluwasegun-akinsola-and-kamilyrb).

Comment: Thank you @kamilyeb, I was able to fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by changing the `filter()` to `get()` and using the try and except to catch error.

```
def import_city_from_file(self):
        data_folder = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'app_name', 'resources/city_csv')
        for data_file in os.listdir(data_folder):
            with open(os.path.join(data_folder, data_file), encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
                data = csv.reader(data_file)
                for data_object in data:
                    country = None
                    state = None
                    try:
                        country = models.Country.objects.get(id=data_object[0])
                    except:
                        pass
                    try:
                        state = models.State.objects.get(state_code=str(data_object[1]))

                    except:
                        pass
                    long_description_eng = data_object[2]
                    long_description_deu = data_object[3]


                    try:
                        city, created = models.City.objects.get_or_create(
                                id=id,
                                country_id=country,
                                state_id = state,
                                long_description_eng=long_description_eng,
                                long_description_deu=long_description_deu,

                            )
                        if created:
                            city.save()
                            display_format = "\nCity, {}, has been saved."
                            print(display_format.format(city))
                    except Exception as ex:
                        print(str(ex))
                        msg = "\n\nSomething went wrong saving this city: {}\n{}".format(id, str(ex))
                        print(msg)
```